# How to present UIPopover from selected segment of UISegmentedControl

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uikit, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to show popover from selected segment of **UISegmentedControl** which is subview of **UIToolBar**.
Here is my code:

```
// UISegemntedControl
NSArray *segments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
_segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segments];
_segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width/2-128, self.frame.size.height/2-12, 256, 24);
_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
[self addSubview:_segmentedControl];
```

Show popover:

```
- (void)show
{
UIView *view = [toolBar.segmentedControl.subviews objectAtIndex:toolBar.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];

// UIPopoverController
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:view.bounds inView:view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

It works, but every time popover presents from wrong segment. I don't know why...

**UPDATE:**
Solution:

```
float width = toolBar.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/toolBar.segmentedControl.subviews.count;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(toolBar.segmentedControl.frame.origin.x+width*toolBar.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex, toolBar.segmentedControl.frame.origin.y, width, toolBat.segmentedControl.frame.size.height);
...
[popover presentPopoverFromRect:bounds inView:toolBar permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the segments are equal, you can just divide the width of the control by the number of the selected segment.

```
 if ((UISegmentedControl*)sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.segmentedControl.frame.size.width/3, self.segmentedControl.frame.origin.y, aWidth, aHeight)];
```

for a reference take a look
[Get frame from certain UISegmentedControl index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9764884/1597744)

Comment: This is solution. Thank you.