# Set position of nspopover

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller, nspopover

I have a view controller (A), which will show another viewcontroller (B) as a popover.

In my VC (A) is an NSButton with this IBAction:

```
self.presentViewController(vcPopover, asPopoverRelativeTo: myButton.bounds, of: myButton, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .semitransient)
```

The result:

[image]

now I would like to change the position of my popover - I would like to move it up.

I tried this:

```
let position = NSRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 120.0), size: CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0))
self.presentViewController(vcPopover, asPopoverRelativeTo: position, of: myButton, preferredEdge: .maxX, behavior: .semitransient)
```

But the position does not change

**ANOTHER EXAMPLE**

[image]

I have a segmented control. If you click on segment "1" a popover will be shown (same code like above). But the arrow pointed to segment "2" instead to segment "1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, ensure your popover is really an `NSPopover` and not simply an `NSViewController`. Assuming the view controller you want to wrap in the popover has a storyboard id of "vcPopover", getting the content vc would look like:

```
let popoverContentController = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "vcPopover")) as! NSViewController
```

Then, wrap it in a popover:

```
let popover = NSPopover()
popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 200, height: 200) // Or whatever size you want, perhaps based on the size of the content controller
popover.behavior = .semitransient
popover.animates = true
popover.contentViewController = popoverContentController
```

Then, to present, call [`show(relativeTo:of:preferredEdge:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover/1532113-show):

```
vcPopover.show(relativeTo: myButton.bounds, of: myButton, preferredEdge: .maxX)
```

This should update the position of the popover.

**Update:** You are likely using an `NSSegmentedControl`, which means you need to pay special attention to the rect you pass in `show`. You need to pass a bounds rect *within the segmented control's coordinate system* that describes the area of the segment. Here's a detailed example:

```
// The view controller doing the presenting
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    ...

    var presentedPopover: NSPopover?

    @IBAction func selectionChanged(_ sender: NSSegmentedControl) {
        let segment = sender.selectedSegment

        if let storyboard = storyboard {
            let contentVC = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier("vcPopover")) as! NSViewController

            presentedPopover = NSPopover()
            presentedPopover?.contentSize = NSSize(width: 200, height: 200)
            presentedPopover?.behavior = .semitransient
            presentedPopover?.animates = true
            presentedPopover?.contentViewController = contentVC
        }

        presentedPopover?.show(relativeTo: sender.relativeBounds(forSegment: segment), of: sender, preferredEdge: .minY)
    }

}

extension NSSegmentedControl {

    func relativeBounds(forSegment index: Int) -> NSRect {
        // Assuming equal widths
        let segmentWidth = bounds.width / CGFloat(segmentCount)

        var rect = bounds
        rect.size.width = segmentWidth
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + segmentWidth * CGFloat(index)

        return rect
    }

}
```

Notice that the extension to `NSSegmentedControl` calculates an approximate rectangle for the segment using the width. This method assumes equal widths and does not account for borders. You may modify this method to account for what you need. Information about getting the frame of a segment for iOS (which is similar) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764804/get-frame-from-certain-uisegmentedcontrol-index).

This example is verified as working correctly as long as a view controller exists in the same storyboard with a storyboard identifier of "vcPopover".

Comment: I declared my vcPopover like this: `let vcPopover = NSStoryboard(name: NSStoryboard.Name(rawValue: "Main"), bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "vcPopover")) as! NSViewController`. I get the error: Value of type 'NSViewController' has no member 'show'

Comment: @Ghost108 I updated my answer with instructions on creating the `NSPopover`.

Comment: I tried your code, but the result is the same, like the picture above. the popover arrow will point to the second segment instead of the first segment. i played with the values of `CGPoint(x: 100.0, y: 120.0)`, but nothing changed

Comment: Are you simply using horizontal `NSButton`s or an `NSSegmentedControl`? In the case of the latter, where are you getting `myButton`?

Comment: @Ghost108 I apologize. I created a sample project and was able to get my version working. I'll add my code to my answer.

Comment: If i try your last code version, the popover does not appear if i pressed the button

Comment: @Ghost108 Did you hook up the IBAction to the control?

Comment: sure ... i get also a print("Hello") if I pressed the button - but no popover

Comment: @Ghost108 I’ve verified that the code works in my own project, so it’s probably just a small difference in how you have your project set up. Is the view controller doing the presenting created from the same Storyboard? If you check in the debugger you may find that ‘self.storyboard’ is returning ‘nil’ and you may want to use your original method of getting the storyboard.

Comment: I only use one storyboard. can you send me your example project, so I can compare ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155836/discussion-between-matthew-seaman-and-ghost108).